# Subprocess for loop fails with syntax error

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a simple script in order to understand how one can run a shell for loop inside a subprocess call. I'm running it from GNU/Linux, inside a virtual enviroment and a BASH shell.

The script:

```
from subprocess import call

shellCommand = ['for','c','in','$(seq 1 10)','do','echo','$c','done']
call(shellCommand, shell=True)
```

And the error message:

```
c: 1: c: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That's not valid shell syntax, no. This is not really a Python problem, the same command would fail when run from a shell directly.

Comment: And for shell commands, just pass in a single string, not a list: `shell_command = 'for c in $(seq 1 10); do echo $c; done', then `call(shell_command, shell=True)`. Note the semicolons I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- Your shell syntax is simply not valid, you are missing key semicolons or newlines.
- You can't pass in a complete shell script as separate arguments.

The correct syntax is:

```sh
for c in $(seq 1 10); do echo $c; done
```

Note the `;` after the `for ... in ...` part before `do`, and another one after each command inside the `do ... done` block. You could also use newlines:

```sh
for c in $(seq 1 10)
do
    echo $c
done
```

Put your whole shell script in *one argument*; the argument is passed to `sh -c ...` and the `-c` switch expects the whole script in a single argument value:

```
shell_command = 'for c in $(seq 1 10); do echo $c; done'
call(shell_command, shell=True)
```

or, alternatively, using newlines:

```
shell_command = 'for c in $(seq 1 10)\ndo\n    echo $c\ndone'
call(shell_command, shell=True)
```

or

```
shell_command = '''
for c in $(seq 1 10)
do
    echo $c
done
'''
call(shell_command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do this sort of thing at the Python layer.

```
# for i in $(seq 10); do ...; done
for i in range(10):
  subprocess.call([...])

# for f in *.py; do ...; done
py_files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') where f.endswith('*.py')]
for f in py_files:
  subprocess.call([..., f, ...])
```

If at all possible you should avoid using `shell=True` because it is actually dangerous.  Consider a filename or user input that contains a `;` or a  in it: how do you protect against it not doing what you expect (and how do you protect against a caller running any shell command on behalf of your process)?  The array form avoids this problem.